# Facing issue with Tomcat execution in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling tomcat after removing the server instance from the eclipse environment. I spent so much time yet there is no use. This is the error I keep receiving.
[Error in the eclipse environment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg0dk.png)

It says that the port 8080 required by Tomcat is in use. But in port 8080 only tomcat is running. I am attaching a screenshot for the same.[Ports in Resource Manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3JPY.png)

Please help me resolve this issue, Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: What you see in _"Resource Manager"_ is Tomcat launched as Windows service, not the one launched by Eclipse. Disable the service in Windows services (or run `Tomcat9w.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

netstat -ano | findstr :

for example, use the below command in the terminal or cmd

netstat -ano | findstr :8080

find the process id
and then use

taskkill /PID  /F
to kill the task.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).